# Add condition in procedure in SQL Server only run in prod environment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that send emails if there are some issues.

I would like to add a condition on that procedure only run in prod environment.

My main question is how can SQL know if the environment is development or production?

Does anyone know if it is possible to do that? And how?

Comment: How does your instance know it's the production environment? Use that with an `IF`.

Comment: Use that with an ```IF```. The conditional check will be based on the value from @@ServerName property. This will be unique for Prod, dev and test instance.

Comment: Have you considered controlling this via permissions? It makes the proc reusable for any of your instances if you have some standard access control management across your org. More importantly, It is resilient to server name changes and non-default instances (more prone to server name changes). You also have better control as only specific prod credentials should be allowed to send mail so doesn't matter where the proc is put, won't do anything unless admin allows it plus relatively easy to disable globally in case of emergency.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @@ServerName = 'ProductionServerName'
    Print 'Production server, running the code'
    /*
    Place here the required code 
    */

Else
    print 'Not Production server'
```